# Change the 'Comment' color in MS Visual Studio Code v 1.6..x

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can you change the 'Comment' color in MS Visual Studio Code v 1.6.1. I understand how to use settings.json to override most settings but cannot find this option

Answer (score -4):

Solved, I simply installed the 'Blackboard' theme which covers my requirement.